# Rails: search in multiple model using sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I'm newbie and want to implement advanced search, I have two model articles and books and I am using sunspot gem for search

this is my articles model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

searchable do
  text :title
  text :content
end
```

this my books model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

searchable do    
  text :title       
  text :description  
end
```

I have tried to implement a search form where user can select which category want to search for like this search form
[image]

but I have not get it so I will appreciate any help in how can I do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> Sunspot.search [Article, Book] do
>     ....
>      end

Answer (score 0):

```
@r=Sunspot.search [Article,Book] do |query| 
        query.fulltext params[:keyword]+"\*"  
end 
@results=@r.results
```